# Why doesn't my padding apply to an anchor though it does apply to a button?

Tags: html, css

Take This code for example

```css
.ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: black solid 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.btn {
  padding: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li">
    <button class="btn">
      Button Here
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="li">
    <a class="btn" href="#">
      Link Here
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want apply padding on `<a>` but it is not working

[image]

I know i can apply padding on `<li>` but it will not work because when i apply padding the whole thing is not click able only the `<a>` part is

Comment: make it inline-block - you cannot apply vertical padding to inline elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an inline-block on the class "btn" so you can have margins and paddings added on the four sides.
Different from the inline elements that you can't add vertical paddings.

```
.btn {
  padding: 20px !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
}
```